# How to number contents of a list as it is printed

Tags: python

To be more specific, I'm using this to print out each title in a list

```
for title in list:
    print (title)
```

Is there a way to make so that when each title is printed it is numbered. For example when it prints out it looks like this:

```
1. title1
2. title2
3. title3
```

etc...

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: you can achieve this by using a simple counter

Comment: NB: you should also avoid shadowing built-in types (e.g., `list`) with variable/name references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop :

```
for i in range(len(my_list)) :
    print( str(i + 1) + '. ' + str(my_list[i]) )
```

Or a while loop :

```
i = 0 
while i < len(my_list) : 
    print( str(i + 1) + '. ' + str(my_list[i]) )
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to count the items in the list as you iterate through them.  Also, `list` is a built-in function, so you should use a different name for your list.

```
for i,title in enumerate(my_list):
    print('{}. {}'.format(i+1, title))
```